# block layered filter/category filter into manufacturers page in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I have enabled the Layered Navigation module and make the position first in displayleft column, its working fine in category page,but not showing in manufacture page. I need same left column/filter in manufacture page also.

Please guide.

Comment: post some code etc. SO is not code writing service.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma, blocklayered is prestashop inbuilt/free module,so what kind of code i have to post,i want to move that module to manufacture page,if you have any idea please share?

Comment: @raj I just edited your post by correcting spellings. I am not asking for any code. Infact @M U is asking for code not me.

Comment: @RahulSharma,sorry for  this.

Comment: @raj no issues bro.. **Peace**

Answer (score 0):

The module `blocklayered` doesn't work in manufacturer and supplier page. I'm sorry.
You have to use another module, search on the addons, the official PrestaShop module shop.
Cheers.

Comment: ,Thanks for reply,yes i tried to find addons,one i got but unfortunately its paid version,i just looking the idea how to get that filter category code into manufacture page,may be calling some hook or something,if you have any idea please share??

Comment: I guess you have to edit `getFilterBlock` method, and modify queries, results, a lot of work... Trust me, buy a module :D